# Perl sorting minimal values with filtering zeros

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, filtering

I have the perl code where sorting is choozing the minimal value, but if the one value is 0, it should be ignored.
This is sorting function without filtering:

```
sub desc_Emin
{
 my($emin)=(sort{$b<=>$a} @_)[-1];
 return $emin;
}
```

And this function is called and takes values:

```
$desc_mv[$n]=desc_Emin($descs_a[$n],$descs_b[$n],$descs_c[$n]);
```

For example, there is the list:

```
descs_a  descs_b  descs_c
1        4        5
0        1        3
0        0        0
2        2        0
```

After sorting it [$desc_mv] should be:

```
1
1
0
2
```

How to filter without adding a lot of 'if' statements? It is better to filter zeros in the  "$desc_mv[$n]=desc_Emin(..." part?

My fast temporal solution looks like:

```
            if($descs_a[$n] == $descs_b[$n] and $descs_b[$n] == $descs_c[$n] ){
            $desc_mv[$n]=$descs_a[$n];                  
            }
            else{

            use Switch;
            switch($descs_a[$n]){
                case 0 {$descs_a[$n] = 99999999999999};                     
            }
            use Switch;
            switch($descs_b[$n]){
                case 0 {$descs_b[$n] = 99999999999999};
            }
            use Switch;
            switch($descs_c[$n]){
                case 0 {$descs_c[$n] = 99999999999999};
            }

            $desc_mv[$n]=desc_Emin($descs_a[$n],$descs_b[$n],$descs_c[$n]);
            }
```

Comment: When you need to find something you should use `grep/map/for`, not `sort`.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov But I have numerical values, why I should use grep and map? `$descs_a[1]` is already `1` and `$descs_c[1]` is `0`. The code is not written by me - I am using it and trying to fix this bug.

Comment: I don't get your question. Are you somehow thinking `grep` is for strings? No, it isn't.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Yes, this is my firs time working with real editing of perl scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You need to scan over all values, skip 0 and remember each new value if it is smaller than previously remembered. Just write that out exactly, in Perl:

```
sub desc_Emin {
    my $min = 0;
    for my $val (@_) {
        # if we're remembering 0, replace it with anything OR (if new value is not 0 and smaller than what we remember, remember that)
        if ($min == 0 || ($val != 0 && $min > $val)) { $min = $val }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for.